# Upgrade python 3.4 to python 3.6 on rpi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

As title states. I want to upgrade my python version on my raspberry pi from 3.4 to 3.6.

I have tried

```
sudo apt-get upgrade python3
```

But it doesn't work:

> Calculating upgrade... python3 is already the newest version

I have also tried to get it from python's website. I got a zip file but what do I do with it?

Sorry for noob questions

Comment: Which zip-file did you download? Did you tried to unpack it? Is there a README.txt file or similar? Did you read it?

Comment: duplicate of sister site: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/59381/how-do-i-update-my-rpi3-to-python-3-6

Answer (score 7, accepted):

build it from source (it will take a while about 40minutes)

```
    $wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.5/Python-3.6.5.tar.xz
    $tar -xf Python-3.6.5.tar.xz
    $cd Python-3.6.5
    $./configure
    $make -j4 #you have 4 cores on your cpu
    $sudo make install
```

Comment: I ran the code and I think it worked! Hpw do I open the actual shell and editor? I can only access the python shell from the terminal